# Why do TTime comparisons give unexpected results?

Tags: delphi, datetime, delphi-2010

I have observed some kind of weird behaviour regarding the `EncodeDateTime` and `EncodeTime` methods and I am seeking some explanation.

```
procedure SomeTestCase;
var
    time: TTime;
    dateTime: TDateTime;
begin
    time := EncodeTime(8, 0, 0, 0);
    date := EncodeDateTime(2012, 11, 2, 8, 0, 0, 0);

    Assert(time = TimeOf(date)); //Fails
end;
```

What I've found is that `date`'s hour portion evaluates to `7:59:59` instead of `8:00:00`. But if I set the hour portion of `time` and `date` to 9, the assert passes and `date` evaluates to the expected value. Some hours work while some others don't. Can somebody explain me what is going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A time value (`TTime`, `TDate`, `TDateTime`) is actually a `double` (that is, a floating-point value), with the date encoded in the integer part, and the time encoded in by fractional part. And it is always risky to test equality of floating-point values.

You can use `SameTime(time, date)` instead. This compensates correctly for 'numerical fuss': `Result := Abs(Frac(A) - Frac(B)) < OneMillisecond;`