# Using TTime as the key of a TDictionary

Tags: delphi, datetime, dictionary, delphi-2010

I want to use `TTime` as the key of a `TDictionary`, but I encountered a problem with TTime comparisons and therefore I am seeking for an alternative to this.

My particular problem is that I am trying to build some kind of agenda with the hours on the side, represented with a `TTime` object and I store them in a `TDictionary` alongside their top coordinate. Given the hour of the task I want to draw on the grid, I can retrieve its top coordinate easily from the dictionary based on the hour of the tasks. Unfortunately, it does not work because [`TTime` comparisons give unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201535/why-do-ttime-comparisons-give-unexpected-results). I cannot reliably retrieve the coordinate from the dictionary with a `TTime`.

- How would you solve this problem?
- Would you skip the TDictionary thing altogether and go with another approach?

Comment: I think this is a perfectly valid question and I would like that the downvoters explain themselves.

Comment: It doesn't work is not enough

Comment: If you saw my linked question, then you would understand why it does not work.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I edited my question, please reconsider your downvote, or simply ask me what details you need.

Comment: How about using a TTimeStamp as the key instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `TDictionary` constructor accepts an `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` argument, which it will use for comparing the key values. Implement that interface for `TTime` (by inheriting from [`TEqualityComparer`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Generics.Defaults.TEqualityComparer)) and use [`SameTime`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.DateUtils.SameTime) to perform the comparison.

Comment: That's a good answer. It's probably most convenient to use TEqualityComparer.Construct. It might be a little tricky to write the hash function though. To do so, you'd need to make it compatible with SameTime's implementation.

Comment: The hash code can be anything you want, as long as it is unique to the value being hashed.  Since that would be a `TTime`, I would suggest decoding it into its hour, minute, second, and millisecond components and then bit-shift them into a single Integer. They will fit nicely (the hours requires 5 bits, the minutes and seconds require 6 bits each, and the milliseconds requires 10 bits, for a total of 27 bits) and you won't lose any precision.

Comment: DateTimeToTimeStamp will produce a unique integer that has the advantage over a has of being an accurate representation of the TTime.  ;-)

Comment: @remy That's not accurate. Two not equal values can have the same hash.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: If two `TTime` values do not represent the exact same hour/minute/second/msec then they could not produce the same hash using either technique mentioned.

Comment: @Remy I'm not talking about implementation. I'm talking about the requirements for a valid hash function. Your statement that it must be "unique to the value being hashed" is incorrect.